# CreateNavigationDrawer Right Side React Native

Tags: react-native, navigation-drawer, react-navigation

How to Make the Navigation Drawer In React Native slide from the right Side, I tried position: right but it doesnt work

```
 export default createDrawerNavigator({

 Home:{
 screen: AppStackNav,
 navigationOptions: {
  drawerIcon: ({tintColor}) => (
    <Icon name = 'ios-home' style={{fontSize:24, color: tintColor}}/>
  ),
  drawerLabel: "Home",

}},

Setting: {
screen: SettingScreen,
navigationOptions: {
    drawerLabel: "Setting",
    drawerIcon: ({tintColor}) => (
      <Icon name = 'ios-settings' style={{fontSize:24, color: tintColor}}/>
    )}},
{
    contentComponent: CustomDrawerComponent

  },{
   drawerPosition: 'right',}

);
```

Comment: To give you a great answer, it might help us if you have a glance at [ask] if you haven't already. It might be also useful if you could provide a [mcve].

Answer (score 3):

You need to add
drawerPosition: 'right'
inside screenOptions tag. like This
<Drawer.Navigator

```
        initialRouteName="HomeScreen"
        screenOptions={{ headerShown: false, drawerPosition:"right" }}}>
```

</Drawer.Navigator>

Answer (score 1):

Closing bracket of component was missing and **drawerPosition** should be the first parameter after closing bracket of component. Works fine now.

```
const Hello = createDrawerNavigator({
     Home:{
     screen: AppStackNav,
     navigationOptions: {
      drawerIcon: ({tintColor}) => (
        <Icon name = 'ios-home' style={{fontSize:24, color: tintColor}}/>
      ),
      drawerLabel: "Home",

    }},

    Setting: {
    screen: SettingScreen,
    navigationOptions: {
        drawerLabel: "Setting",
        drawerIcon: ({tintColor}) => (
          <Icon name = 'ios-settings' style={{fontSize:24, color: tintColor}}/>
        )}}
      },{
       drawerPosition: 'right',},
    {
        contentComponent: CustomDrawerComponent

      }

    );
```

Answer (score 1):

React Navigation v5

```
import {createDrawerNavigator} from '@react-navigation/drawer';
const Drawer = createDrawerNavigator();
```

then on Drawer.Navigator

> drawerPosition="right"

like this

```
   <Drawer.Navigator
      drawerPosition="right"
      initialRouteName="Home">
      <Drawer.Screen name="Home" component={HomeScreen} />
   </Drawer.Navigator>
```